# Can't get CSS ellipsis to work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm very new to the whole responsive web design and I'm building simple todo app to learn with angularJS. My trouble now is how can I handle text that is too long and breaks the layout.

Here you can see how it breaks. 
[image]

[image]

The HTML&CSS is now :

*note: This is wrapped with `<div class="span12">`*

```
<li>
    <div>
        <span class="taskshorter">{{t.TaskName}}</span>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <span class="label label-info ">{{t.EstimatedTime}}</span>
            <span class="label label-important">{{t.EstimatedTimeLeft}}</span>
            <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

and CSS

```css
.taskshorter {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 20px;
    height: 1.2em;
}
```

But it dosen't seem to work. Should I rather write javascript code to clip the text or Am I missing something that can be easily fixed?

Also I'm using Twitter boostrap fluid layout.

Comment: What do you want to do with the overflow? Just cut it off or wrap the text? First one could be very simple, second one a bit complicated.

Comment: Just cut it off so it dosen't break the layout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't set `width` on an inline element. Add `display:inline-block` to the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

A not-so-clean, but easy workaround would be to give the right element the same background as the main page.

```css
.pull-right {
    background-color: blue; /* your bg color */
    float: right;
    box-shadow: -2px 0 4px blue; /* just for smoother "cut" */
}
```

I haven't tested it, might need some more adjustments. If you put an example into JSFiddle, I could adjust it.